# Using docker during build of Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I tried to build [gitlab-ci-multi-runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/development/README.md) in a docker environment using a Dockerfile. It's no problem to use the Dockerfile to install packages and compile sources. However the buildprocess of gitlab-ci-multi-runner itself involves using docker to prepare a docker image.

Is there a way to give the build environment used for building the Dockerfile access to a docker service?

When *running* a container I can for example use `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` to allow the container access to the host docker process. Is something like this also possible when *building* a Dockerfile?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Usually docker is installed as a system service.

Comment: For docker to work the docker client needs to connect to a server process. It is possible to install the docker client, but for it to actually do things I need to give it access to a docker server. This means I either need to run some docker-in-docker server during build or mount the host socket into the build environment. - If I don't do this the client will correctly complain, that it is not able to reach a server process.

Comment: I see a Dockerfile in the repo (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/Dockerfile) which does not require any Docker-in-Docker. The makefile doesn't contain anything like that neither.

Comment: Please elaborate on what guide you're following, how you started the build, which step the build fails at, and what the exact message is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that Dockerfile. However that Dockerfile does not install any docker package. Therefore the build process complains about not being able to run docker. (It then falls back to downloading a prebuild image.) The question is, how to enable the build to actually build that image instead of using the prebuild one.